# JQuery or Angular JS?

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

Hey guys I am some what new to programming. I've learned some php and now I want to move on to some JQuery. Then I came across AJS or Angular JS. I was wondering what is better to use JQuery or AJS? Or if its a matter of preference. And do they both do the same things or do they each have thier advantages?

I only ask you guys because I can't find any clear answers on google or YouTube. They just show examples of how you can write less with AJS.

Comment: go for angular js, you need to learn Jquery also for better understanding of angular js

Comment: I am learning jquery right now, but why do you say go for AJS

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges. jQuery is primarily a DOM Manipulation library whereas angular is a framework

Comment: Hmm so if I want to include other elements from other files I'd need jquery then right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell:

- jQuery is a JavaScript library.
- AngularJS is a framework.

**jQuery** is basically a wrapper around JavaScript that offers a simplified way of working with JavaScript to perform HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax

**AngularJS** can use jQuery.  By default, it actually uses its own subset of jQuery called jQLite.  AngularJS provides a framework for your application to help tie in your front-end view to your back-end data and business logic.

Here are some links for both to maybe help better understand the differences and what each is used for:

- [AngularJS FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)
- [About jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/)